# How to detect the mobile browsers in php

Tags: php, mobile

I tried this code this code to detect the browsers in mobile

```
<?php
function isMobile() {
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}
// If the user is on a mobile device, redirect them
if(isMobile())
{

  echo 'mobile';
}
else
{
    echo 'desktop';
}
?>
```

But it is not detecting the mobile browsers, can any one tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: You should be designing your site responsively rather than kicking everybody not on a desktop to a stripped down mobile version of the site. Most mobile users don't want this.

Comment: You can use library like this: http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: Have you tried [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` to see what's actually there? Also, this is not the best way to solve the mobile vs. desktop device issue. As @meager said, a responsive design would be best. Also, it's probably not the best idea to have PHP concerned with the type of device visiting your site (that usually happens in JavaScript/CSS). Also, user agent strings can be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ works well too - or Adam's suggestion is good too.